# Convert Z-score (Z-value, standard score) to p-value for normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

How does one convert a [Z-score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) from the [Z-distribution (standard normal distribution, Gaussian distribution)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) to a [*p*-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)? I have yet to find the magical function in [Scipy's `stats` module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) to do this, but one must be there.

Comment: I have started one here http://statsandprobability.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I like the survival function (upper tail probability) of the normal distribution a bit better, because the function name is more informative:

```
p_values = scipy.stats.norm.sf(abs(z_scores)) #one-sided

p_values = scipy.stats.norm.sf(abs(z_scores))*2 #twosided
```

normal distribution "norm"  is one of around 90 distributions in scipy.stats

norm.sf also calls the corresponding function in scipy.special as in gotgenes example

small advantage of survival function, sf: numerical precision should better for quantiles close to 1 than using the cdf

Answer (score 47):

I think the cumulative distribution function (cdf) is preferred to the survivor function. The survivor function is defined as 1-cdf, and may communicate improperly the assumptions the language model uses for directional percentiles. Also, the percentage point function (ppf) is the inverse of the cdf, which is very convenient.

```
>>> import scipy.stats as st
>>> st.norm.ppf(.95)
1.6448536269514722
>>> st.norm.cdf(1.64)
0.94949741652589625
```

Edit:
A user requested an example for ''vectors'':

```
import numpy as np
vector = np.array([.925, .95, .975, .99])
p_values = [st.norm.ppf(v) for v in vector]
f_values = [st.norm.cdf(p) for p in p_values]

for p,f in zip(p_values, f_values):
 print(f'p: {p}, \tf: {f}')
```

Yields:

```
p: 1.4395314709384563,  f: 0.925
p: 1.6448536269514722,  f: 0.95
p: 1.959963984540054,   f: 0.975
p: 2.3263478740408408,  f: 0.99
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete code answer that shows how to convert a vector of Z-scores to a vector of p-values?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper Added

Comment: I may be mistaken, but am I not seeing z-scores and percentiles, but **no** p-values in the above solution? I like the solution a lot; it's just I don't see any p-values; they seem to be z-scores.

Answer (score 12):

Aha! I found it: [`scipy.special.ndtr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtr.html#scipy.special.ndtr)! This also appears to be under `scipy.stats.stats.zprob` as well (which is just a pointer to `ndtr`).

Specifically, given a one-dimensional `numpy.array` instance `z_scores`, one can obtain the p-values as

```
p_values = 1 - scipy.special.ndtr(z_scores)
```

or alternatively

```
p_values = scipy.special.ndtr(-z_scores)
```

Comment: Strange terminology, "Z-distribution" instead of "Normal curve".  Z-score I'd probably call standard deviation in this context as well.

Comment: Well, the Z-distribution == "standard normal distribution" == `N(0, 1)`. That said, your point is well taken. I have updated the question to reflect the various terminology for the same concepts.

Answer (score 8):

Starting `Python 3.8`, the standard library provides the [`NormalDist`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist) object as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module.

It can be used to apply the ***inverse cumulative distribution function*** (**[`inv_cdf`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.inv_cdf)**, also known as the **quantile function** or the **percent-point function**) and the ***cumulative distribution function*** ([`cdf`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.cdf)):

```
NormalDist().inv_cdf(0.95)
# 1.6448536269514715
NormalDist().cdf(1.64)
# 0.9494974165258963
```

Answer (score 3):

From formula:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as scsp
def z2p(z):
    """From z-score return p-value."""
    return 0.5 * (1 + scsp.erf(z / np.sqrt(2)))
```

Comment: This isn't the best solution; it isn't vectorized like the above answer.

Comment: You can get a vectorized version simply by replacing `math.erf` and `math.sqrt` by `erf` and `sqrt` from scipy.

Comment: this is the best solution, if z is not a vector

Answer (score 1):

```py
p_value = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(abs(z_score_max)) #one-sided test 
p_value = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(abs(z_score_max))*2 # two - sided test
```

The probability density function (pdf) function in python yields values p-values that are drawn from a z-score table in a intro/AP stats book.

Answer (score 0):

For Scipy lovers, Tough this is old question but relevant, and we can have not only normal but other distributions as well so here is solution for few more distributions:

```
def get_p_value_normal(z_score: float) -> float:
    """get p value for normal(Gaussian) distribution 

    Args:
        z_score (float): z score

    Returns:
        float: p value
    """
    return round(norm.sf(z_score), decimal_limit)


def get_p_value_t(z_score: float) -> float:
    """get p value for t distribution 

    Args:
        z_score (float): z score

    Returns:
        float: p value
    """
    return round(t.sf(z_score), decimal_limit)


def get_p_value_chi2(z_score: float) -> float:
    """get p value for chi2 distribution 

    Args:
        z_score (float): z score

    Returns:
        float: p value
    """
    return round(chi2.ppf(z_score, df), decimal_limit)
```